# How to read a PDF file from a URL of external site in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-routing, pdf-reader

I want to be able to download a PDF file that is accessed by a routed URL (external site) in my [ASP.NET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET) application.

Is there a way to do it?

The current situation:

The routed URL is in the company's internal site ([Joomla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joomla) site), *http://example/sites/index.php/2011-10-30-12-29-04/finish/11/1234*.
This link is redirecting users to a PDF file.
I need to get this PDF file in my application (PdfReader) using the routed URL.

---

Update #1:

I did some changes to my code as you suggested (I added it in the original question), and just I needed to pass the content stream to my pdfReader. However, it still shows me that download failed..

---

Update #2:

The problem is solved now. I had to pass the contentstream as follows:

```vbnet
Dim pdfReader As New PdfReader(isp:=contentStream)

Public Async Function GetPDFFromCompanyWebsite() As Task(Of HttpResponseMessage)

    Using client As HttpClient = New HttpClient()

        Dim msg As HttpResponseMessage = Await client.GetAsync("http://example/sites/index.php/2011-10-30-12-29-04/finish/4/4088")

        If msg.IsSuccessStatusCode Then

            Dim contentStream = Await msg.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()

            Dim pdfReader As New PdfReader(isp:=contentStream)
            Dim MST As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
            Dim pdfStamper As New PdfStamper(pdfReader, MST)
            For pageIndex As Integer = 1 To pdfReader.NumberOfPages
                Dim pageRectangle As Rectangle = pdfReader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(pageIndex)
                Dim pdfData As PdfContentByte = pdfStamper.GetOverContent(pageIndex)

                pdfData.SetFontAndSize(BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA_BOLD, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED), 40)
                Dim graphicsState As New PdfGState()

                graphicsState.FillOpacity = 0.1F
                pdfData.SetGState(graphicsState)

                pdfData.SetColorFill(BaseColor.BLUE)

                Dim bf As BaseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED)

                pdfData.SetFontAndSize(bf, pageRectangle.Width / 25)
                pdfData.BeginText()
                pdfData.SetFlatness(1000)

                Dim windowsuser As String = User.Identity.Name.Substring(4)
                windowsuser = windowsuser + "        " + windowsuser + "        " + windowsuser + "        " + windowsuser + "        " + windowsuser + "        " + windowsuser + "        " + windowsuser
                '    pdfData.ShowTextAligned(Element.ALIGN_BOTTOM, User.Identity.Name, 100, 100, 45)
                Response.Write("width:height: " + pageRectangle.Width.ToString + " / " + pageRectangle.Height.ToString)
                pdfData.ShowTextAligned(Element.ALIGN_CENTER, windowsuser, pageRectangle.Width / 2, pageRectangle.Height / 2, 45)
                pdfData.ShowTextAligned(Element.ALIGN_CENTER, windowsuser, pageRectangle.Width / 4, pageRectangle.Height - (pageRectangle.Height / 4), 45)
                pdfData.ShowTextAligned(Element.ALIGN_CENTER, windowsuser, pageRectangle.Width - (pageRectangle.Width / 4), pageRectangle.Height / 4, 45)
                pdfData.ShowTextAligned(Element.ALIGN_CENTER, windowsuser, (3 * pageRectangle.Width) / 8, pageRectangle.Height - ((3 * pageRectangle.Height) / 8), 45)
                pdfData.ShowTextAligned(Element.ALIGN_CENTER, windowsuser, pageRectangle.Width - ((3 * pageRectangle.Width) / 8), (3 * pageRectangle.Height) / 8, 45)

                pdfData.EndText()
            Next

            pdfStamper.Close()
            Dim bytesInStream As Byte() = MST.ToArray()

            MST.Close()

            Response.Clear()
            Response.ClearContent()
            Response.ClearHeaders()
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=File.pdf")
            Response.BufferOutput = True
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
            Response.BinaryWrite(bytesInStream)
            Response.End()
            Response.Close()

            '        End Using
        End If

        Return msg
    End Using
End Function
```

Comment: Try making a GET request using HttpClient class and store the result in a ByteArray.

Comment: can you explain how to do that please

Comment: Your update is not in C#, kind of confusing at first to read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try making a GET request to your company's website using the HttpClient class in C#. You can do something along the lines.

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System.IO;

public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetPDFFromCompanyWebsite()
{
string currentDirectory = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~");
string filePath = Path.Combine(currentDirectory, "App_Data", "someDocument.pdf");

using(HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    HttpResponseMessage msg = await client.GetAsync($"http://example/sites/index.php/2011-10-30-12-29-04/finish/11/1234");

    if(msg.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
     using(var file = File.Create(filePath))
     { 
       // create a new file to write to
       var contentStream = await msg.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync(); // get the actual content stream
       await contentStream.CopyToAsync(file); // copy that stream to the file stream
       await file.FlushAsync(); // flush back to disk before disposing
     }
   }
  return msg;
} }
```

Comment: Thank you Kunal, I did some changes to my code as you suggested (I added it in the original question), just I needed to pass the content stream to my pdfReader then to a memory stream. However it still shows me that download failed.

Comment: Try checking that company link, by sending a GET Request to it by [Postman](https://app.getpostman.com/app/download/win64?_ga=2.87234652.557795504.1512549768-1694700739.1504503127) and checking whether you get a response or not?

Comment: The link is working because I tried your method (to write it as a file) and it worked.

Comment: @NajatAl-Naamani if my solution worked for you, you can accept it as your answer.